# Spring MVC start page without web.xml

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am learning SpringMVC from the [Tutorial](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-and-spring-security-4-integration-example/). I can able to see the application automatically redirect to login page and I couldn't able to see anything in `@Controller`. Also, this application has not any web.xml. I'm just wondering where they have set up the start page?

Comment: from the directory snapshot on that page I'd guess `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer`.  Newer versions of the Servlet API (>= 3) no longer require `web.xml`. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html

Comment: @MattWhipple Thanks for your reply.